# Why is the std::map::operator[] logarithmic in complexity relative to number of keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary, time-complexity

Can someone explain why the std::map subscript operator method is logarithmic in complexity (as opposed to linear), relative to the number of keys in the mapping?

(I'm sure this a pretty basic question but I'm new to computational complexity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you are thinking that `std::map` is a hash table which would have a linear complexity (worst case).

`std::map` on the other hand is SORTED which complicates things a lot. By having that requirement you are restricted to data structures that can support sorting (usually red/black trees), from which you get the logarithmic complexity.

`std::unordered_map` on the other hand, has linear complexity (worst case)

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is usually implemented as a red/back-tree (similar to a B-tree), which has a depth of `log(n)` and is roughly height-balanced (there is no large difference in path length from the root to any leaf) thus you need to make at most `log(n)` comparisons to find any element.